# No module named frida

Tags: python, module, frida

To install frida I used the command
`sudo pip install frida-tools` and installation was succesful:

`Installing collected packages: frida, frida-tools
Successfully installed frida-12.7.16 frida-tools-5.1.0`

but when running the command:
`frida --version`

I get the following error:

````
  File "/usr/local/bin/frida", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/frida_tools/repl.py", line 24, in main
    import frida
ImportError: No module named frida```
````

Comment: I hit `ImportError: No module named Frida`.  Turned out everything was ok and I incorrectly capitalized the `F`.  Should have been: `import frida`. Humbled. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo pip3 install frida-tools
```

```
$ unlink /usr/local/bin/python
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

### Alternative

```
$ cd ~/
$ open -e .bash_profile
```

paste to the editor, to the top

```
 alias python='python3'
```

save, then run

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I did and I got the same error 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/frida", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/frida_tools/repl.py", line 24, in main
    import frida
ImportError: No module named frida`

Comment: Can you type ```which python``` to the bash

Comment: `Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ which python
/usr/bin/python
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ 
`

Comment: Are you using python 2.7?

Comment: It is by default on my MacBook Pro, but I used pip3 to install frida.

Comment: Ok, that is the problem. Your default python is python 2.7

Comment: What other python do you have 3.7? Anaconda?

Comment: Hmm, any idea how can I use python3 then?

Comment: Are you using anaconda?

Comment: How can I check if im using anaconda? Sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: Did you ever install Anaconda?

Comment: Can you run ```ls -l /usr/bin/python*```

Comment: No, my version of python is 3.7.4

Comment: 8 proccess running most of them python 2.7 and one of them is 3

Comment: ```/usr/bin/python

/usr/bin/python-config


/usr/bin/python2


/usr/bin/python2.7


/usr/bin/python2.7-config


/usr/bin/python3


/usr/bin/pythonw 


/usr/bin/pythonw2.7```

Comment: ok, now can you run ```python3``` to bash. Once, you give it to me, I know what to do.

Comment: ```Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep 28 2019, 16:39:19) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.```

Comment: When doing the last step I get these:
`-bash: /Users/david/.bash_profile: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/david/.bash_profile: line 3: `export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATHif command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then'`

Comment: ok, just close the terminal and reopen it and try the alternative

Comment: I tried navigation to the directory of python but I have no such directory, I have python3, python3-config, python3.7,python3.7-config,python3.7m,python3.7m-config

Comment: what about this ```ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python```

Comment: Okay that didn't gave me any errors, tried to run frida --version again I got the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
sudo pip install frida
```

If did not work try to test in a virtual enviroment:

```
virtualenv env && source env/bin/activate && pip install frida-tools
```

If did not work check if your pip version point to same python version:

```
sudo pip -V
> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

sudo python -V
> Python 3.6.8
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

write command with first python like :

```
python test.py
```

for me not working without "python" and get error: ImportError: No module named frida

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31987339)